# "Допустимое расстояние (—) не менее 50 см". Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Проверьте, пожалуйста, пунктуацию.
**Допустимое расстояние — не менее 50 см.**

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

Пунктуация корректна, только дефис надо заменить на тире:

**Допустимое расстояние — не менее 50 см.**

Тире стоит вместо пропущенного сказуемого *составляет".

Comment: Прочёл Ваш ответ и задумался. А ведь на клавиатурах - как физических, так и экранных - 
нет символа "тире", есть именно "дефис". Вот видите, у меня тут дефисы.  
Правда, в некоторых текстовых редакторах работает автозамена, но она не всегда работает корректно.  Поставить именно тире иногда можно, но это требует дополнительных усилий. А иногда такой символ вообще не предусмотрен.

Comment: @РоманБабаев Увы, требует усилий — нужно нажать ALT-0151, но затраты энергии при этом не очень велики :)

Comment: Я пользуюсь почти исключительно мобильными приложениями. В них ALT-0151 отсутствует.

Comment: @РоманБабаев Я задал вопрос на Мете: https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8

Comment: @М_Г Ой-ёй, правила вопрос через "первые сообщения" (там ведь не видно ни ответа, ни комментариев). Дефис, соответственно, исправила на тире. КАК теперь быть?

Comment: @М_Г Спасибо. Скажите, пожалуйста, почему я раньше (в предыдущем комментарии) тоже вручную набирал <собаку и Ваш ник>, а оно удалялось; а теперь не удалилось? Вроде и пытался help по этому сайту читать, но как-то пока не всё получается :)

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Вот и хорошо! Тире — это верный знак. Пред нами не стоит задача сохранять ошибки оригинала.

Comment: @РоманБабаев Это вопрос к мoдeратору (@Aer).